# By pass security code in selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

So basically, I'm new with selenium webdriver (python). I have managed to create plenty of scripts. But recently I having difficulty when the site that I login in using selenium required their user to input the verification code that is sent to their email. Is there any workaround for this? Any suggestions are considered, thanks.

Comment: If it could be bypassed by someone not authorized to do so, that would rather be defeating the point. (If *you're* authorized to be scraping the site, then talk to the folks running it, and they should work out an accommodation for you -- client certificates, or an API key, or some other type).

Comment: You have to talk to the developers. Ask them to provide a secret token for testing. Then you can add that token to cookies or session. Please note that the secret token it should work on development environment only.

Comment: Actually I have the security code sent to my email. What I meant is that can I shorten the process and avoiding the security check? Like for example using cookies that I set up previously into the script. or any other solutions @CharlesDuffy

Comment: But the problem is that the script should also work on both development and production. One of the steps required me to access another services. @Buaban

Comment: @JoguesPermana if your application verify credentials or token in cookies, and there is no heartbeat or timeout check; you can save the values to a file and then reuse it by add them to cookies. Take a look at this [article](http://www.whiteboxtest.com/selenium2-WebDriver-Binary-Profile-And-Cookies.php).

Comment: Thank you @Buaban will check that link.

Comment: If the code is generated each time as it should be, then you should read it from email, see if you can use an email service that can also provide an api for reading the emails.

Comment: Ahh is it possible that way? to get email api to read the emails? Will look into it. Thank you @lauda